# Is there a continuous bijection?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know there is a bijection from $(0,1) $ to $(0,1] $.

Are there functions
 $f,g:(0,1) \to (0,1] $  where $f$ is a continuous surjection and $g$ is a continuous bijection?

Comment: For continuous surjection, I am thinking of functions like

$$f(x) = 4x(1-x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous surjection: $f(x) = 2x$ for $x \le 1/2$, $f(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 1/2$.

Continuous bijection: Assume $f : (0,1) \to (0,1]$ is one. Let $x_1 \in (0,1)$ be the point such that $f(x_1) = 1$. Let $x_2 = x_1/2$ and $x_3 = x_1 + (1-x_1)/2$. Then $0 < t_i = f(x_i) < 1$ for $i = 2,3$. Let $m = \max(t_2,t_3)$  and $\tau \in (m,1)$. By the IVT we find $\xi_i$ between $x_1$ and $x_i$ such that $f(\xi_i) = \tau$. Clerly $\xi_2 < x_1 < \xi_3$, contradicting the fact that $f$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn’t exists: if $f: (0,1)\to (0,1]$ is a bijection, calling $b\in (0,1)$ so that $f(b)=1$ you have that the restriction of $f$ on $(0,1)- \{ b\} $ is a function from a not-connected space to a connected one, so $f$ can’t be continous. 
(I used that the restriction of a continous function must be continous)